Increasing the probability of membership in an elliptic curve
Suppose $R$ is an elliptic curve and $G$ is a group on it (the order of group is $n$ which is a big prime number). Also suppose $P_1 \in G$ and $P_2\in G$ and $M \subset G , (|M|=m)$. $M$ is a subset of $G$. Now consider the equation $Z = (P_1)^{\alpha_1}(P_2)^{\alpha_2}$ and ${\alpha_1},{\alpha_2}$ have been arbitrary chosen. The probability that we have $Z \in M$ is $\frac{m}{n}$. Now the question is how to choose  ${\alpha_1},{\alpha_2}$ to increase this probability . I mean find ${\alpha_1},{\alpha_2}$ in such a way that the probability of $Z \in M$ is more than  $\frac{m}{n}$

What do you mean with $Z = (P_1)^{\alpha_1}(P_2)^{\alpha_2}$? Is $n$ prime or composite?

n is a big prime number and $G$ has no subgroup, $Z$ is multiple of of two elements (${P_1}^{\alpha_1} $and ${P_2}^{\alpha_2} $)

If $n$ is prime, then except the identity, all elements have order $n$. So, what is the question here, then?

Make it clear that $M$ is a subset of $G$ it is not a subgroup.

$M$ is subset of $G$  and $G$ has no subgroup

How do you multiply two points? What is  $(P_1)^{\alpha_1}$?

to answer this question(How do you multiply two points?) you need to learn more about elliptic curve cryptography
